# Why is Xcopy ignoring /i flag?

Tags: xcopy

This may take the cake for the simplest questions asked here but I have a script that I want to just copy a file and not prompt me with "Does C:\Filename.bin specify a filename or a directory?"

The command is just

```
xcopy C:\sourceFolder\sourceFile.bin C:\destFolder\destFile.bin /i
```

but it keeps prompting me.
I am running this on Server 2003.
Maybe I just need to go to lunch.

Answer (score 1):

[From the xcopy technet page:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254(v=ws.10).aspx)

> If Source is a directory or contains wildcards and Destination does not exist, xcopy assumes Destination specifies a directory name and creates a new directory. Then, xcopy copies all specified files into the new directory. By default, xcopy prompts you to specify whether Destination is a file or a directory.

Since you're not using a wildcard, /I is ignored. You might want /q.